# Is it worth it using a prepared mysql statement for one query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If I have a simple prepared query like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
```

And I only execute the query once during the lifetime of the page.

Is it worth it using a prepared mysql statements for queries like that?

Comment: are you asking about performance? what are your performance issues that you are trying to address?

Comment: Yes, protects against SQL injections.

Comment: Absolutely yes!

Comment: If it is user supplied data (POST,GET) etc  then YES. If static data (?) then probably not

Comment: Basically you are asking: "Is security really worth it for only one query?". It's the same as asking "Should I wear my seatbelt for only one trip down the road?". The answer is of course "Yes".

Comment: How is the security relevant here? When I don't use prepared statements I just escape any variables used in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want most of all here is the security of *parameterised queries.* The API to do parameterised queries happens to be the same as the one for prepared statements. Or in other words, the API that enables the separation of the query structure from the submission of the values kills two birds with one stone:

1. Safe transfer of arbitrary values to the database engine.
2. Reusability of already parsed queries.

It's worth it if you're just using one of them, you don't need to use both aspects at the same time to justify the use of the `prepare` API.

The alternative of manually escaping values is always more error prone and verbose.